# sharepoint file sharing issue

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2013, file-sharing

Dear Sharepoint Expert,

I am new to sharepoint and i am facing an issue on Sharepoint 2013:

There  is a user X that has admin access:

he Created a webpart, and uploaded files(zip files) there, and shared it with some users,
the users were able to see those files.

after a while when uploading new zip files, and sharing them with others the scenario is:

the user shared with receives an email and when he clicks on the link in the email it take him to the webpart but does not show the zip just uploaded and shared with him.

Any Idea?

Comment: Are the zip files stored in a standard document library?  Have you got an example of the code?  Are you relying on security trimming to get applicable uploaded files?

Comment: Are the files Checked in, is Versioning enabled on the library